# Function as argument to another function can update a list, but not an integer

Tags: python

```
def node_count(tree):
   if is_leaf_node(tree):
      return 0
   count = 1
   def inc_count(node): #node argument not used her, but needed in call
      count += 1
  tree_traversal(tree, inc_count)
  return count
```

*tree_traversal* applies a function to each node in the tree and works fine.
This method gives me: 
*UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment*

But this works:

```
 def node_count(tree):
    if is_leaf_node(tree):
       return 0
    l = []
    def inc_count(node): #node argument not used her, but needed in call
       l.append(1) #Add whatever
    tree_traversal(tree, inc_count)
    return len(l)
```

Why?

The last method works, but looks strange. Any other ways of doing it?

Comment: Briefly: in the first code block, you are doing an assignment. In the second, you are mutating a mutable object. If you attempted to reassign the `list` in the second code block, you'd see similar behavior. You can read more in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The first is assigning `count` to `count + 1`.  Since you are using the same variable name on both sides of `=`, Python assumes that you are talking about the same object in both cases.  `count`, however, was not declared `global` (or `nonlocal` in Python 3), so you are trying to assign the local `count` to the local `count` + 1.  Problem: there is no such thing as a local `count` yet.  The solution (**in Python 3**):

```
def node_count(tree):
   if is_leaf_node(tree):
      return 0
   count = 1
   def inc_count(node): #node argument not used her, but needed in call
      nonlocal count
      count += 1
  tree_traversal(tree, inc_count)
  return count
```

There doesn't seem to be a nice, easy solution in Python 2, but you can at least use an actual number in the list instead of finding the sum:

```
def node_count(tree):
   if is_leaf_node(tree):
      return 0
   count = [1]
   def inc_count(node): #node argument not used her, but needed in call
      count[0] += 1
  tree_traversal(tree, inc_count)
  return count[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python3, try to use `nonlocal`:

```
def node_count(tree):
    if is_leaf_node(tree):
        return 0
    count = 1
    def inc_count(node): #node argument not used her, but needed in call
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
    tree_traversal(tree, inc_count)
    return count
```

For Python2, you can reference to [PEP 3104 - Access to Names in Outer Scopes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/)

Answer (score 0):

In python, non-local variables are allowed to be implicitly used, but only for reading.

That is, in your code:

```
count = 0
def inc_count(node):
    count += 1
```

The second use of `count` is a non-local reference that would be allowed if you were not trying to modify it. But modification of non-local symbols is considered a source of error, so you are required to explicitly acknowledge that you know it's not local.

In python 3, you can use the `nonlocal` keyword for this purpose, or the `global` keyword for globals. In python 2, only the `global` keyword was available.

A list is a funny thing, though. You can't modify the list, but you can read it. Since a list is really a pointer to an underlying object, you can "read" it and then use an operator such as `[]` on its value. This appears to work around the no-modification-without-declaration rule.

If you're doing python 2, and don't have the `nonlocal` statement, you might consider doing something like `count = [0]` and then later `count[0] += 1`.

Comment: You certainly *can* modify the list.  Assignments and modifications are two completely different operations.

Comment: Which was exactly my point: you can read it and then use [] on it.

Comment: Wording is important when you are teaching beginners.  The list can be modified (such as `.append()` or `.extend()`), but it cannot be reassigned.